# Excel file Created in C# cannot be opened

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, excel-2010

After Creating an Excel file using C#, I'm trying to open the file, and get the following exception:

**"excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extention matches the format of the file."**

Any suggestions?

Comment: post the code that you used to create the excel

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you post the code so we can see how you are creating the excel.

Comment: -1 for not showing what you actually did to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code and by reading the error, I have the suspect that you're specifing the wrong extension in the path when you save the file, which is a common mistake:

```
string path = "C:\\excelfile.xls"; //or xlsx as said @JMK
```

Comment: Or the OP is specifying the wrong extension, ie xls instead of xlsx or vice versa. If using Interop, there is an argument in the Save method which specifies the type of file to save as, but we have no code to look at.